# The use of "there is" and "there's"

Tags: word-choice

I was studying the use of "there's" and "there is". I summarised their use. Is everything correct?
"There's" informal but it is preferred. In #3, #4, and #5 "there 's" but not "there is" is used because, "there's" is preferred.
In each of these most native speakers would use either "there's" or "there are" but not "there is".

A singular noun with a singular noun:

1. "There is a hammer and a screwdriver in the car."

A singular noun with plural nouns:

2. "There is a hammer and two screwdrivers in the car."

Plural nouns with a singular noun:

3. "There are two screwdrivers and a hammer in the car."

Plural nouns with plural nouns:

4. "There are computers and two desks in my room."

Plural noun with singular nouns:

5. "There are two computers, a desk, and a sofa in my room."

Answer (score 1):

English is not my mother language but I will tell you my opinion!

1."There is a hammer and a screwdriver in the car."This sentence is correct! We can also say "There are a hammer and a screwdriver in the car."This sentence sounds awkward because the noun " a hammer "that follows " there are " is singular!In this case it's better to use " is".Some language commentators still insist on using "are" in sentences like this despite the awkwardness.

2."There is a hammer and two screwdrivers in the car."This sentence is correct! We can also say "There are a hammer and two screwdrivers in the car."Some language commentators still insist on using" are" in sentences like this despite the awkwardness.

3."There are two screwdrivers and a hammer in the car."This sentence is correct!

4."There are computers and two desks in my room."This sentence is correct!

5."There are two computers, a desk, and a sofa in my room."This sentence is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *there's* is informal for *there is*. In very casual speech it might also be used for *there are*.

Preferred by whom? *There's* is certainly not preferred in correct speech, but it is widely used in informal conversation.

*There are* is correct when speaking of more than one item, though we might well use *there's* in informal speech.

Comment: Thank you very much! In 3 4 and 5 it is not wrong to use "there's" and "there is". Right?

Comment: Read my last sentence again! It is incorrect to say _there is_ when speaking of several items, but _there's_ could be acceptable in colloquial speech.

Comment: There is a hammer and a screwdriver in the car.
There is a hammer and two screwdrivers in the car.
There are two screwdrivers and a hammer in the car."

- Declerk, Renaat (1991). A Comprehensive Descriptive Grammar of English, p. 269. Kaitakusha, Japan.  The book says "There is" then it isn't impossible either.

Comment: OK, https://www.grammarly.com/blog/there-is-there-are/ seems to think it can be acceptable - see under _There Is vs. There Are With a Series of Items_